# Rails 4 - How to serve video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm using Rails 4 for my web application and I'm using VideoJS to display it, like:

```
<video id="video1" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="{{pCtrl.video.poster}}"  src="<%= @video.file %>">
        <source src="<%= @video.file %>" type="video/<%= @video.file.file.filename.last(3) %>">
</video>
```

I was always getting this error from VideoJS:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.
```

When I open Chrome's developper tools, I see that the video (the 340Mb .mp4 file) is downloaded with status 206 (Partial Content) and only 2.8 Mb.

I thought it was a problem with VideoJS, but then I tried to access directly, like "http://localhost:3000/uploads/video/file/glrbfmso1449450792.mp4"

The video would play for a few seconds and then it freezes and it won't play unless I refresh the page. I think it only plays the 2.8 Mb loaded. So I believe it has something to do with WEBrick.

The problem is not with the video file, as it plays normally on VLC and when I'm using Glassfish (programming in Java).

My question, then, is: Is there something I should configure in Rails or WEBrick? Is there any settings that I should edit? Or is this what I'm going through unusual?

Comment: Are you streaming this video though the application or does the web server handle it?

Comment: What do you mean? It's like a youtube. You load an HTML page with the "video" tag. I'll update my question

Comment: Where is the video hosted?

Comment: You should probably not use the default rails server (WEBrick?) to serve video files. Locally, it might help to install something like thin. In production, you'd use nginx or similar to serve static assets.

Comment: Actually, it's on development. So I'm using WEBrick locally. Maybe that's why?

Comment: Can I suggest rewording this question to "What is the best way to serve video from a rails application?". You might get more traffic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use rails to serve video files. Although servers such as unicorn support streaming video files there are a few reasons why it's a bad idea. There are vastly different  connections at play here. A rails app generally should take no longer than ~200ms to return a response. When your streaming video it would not be uncommon for the connection to stay open for much longer.

Why does that matter? Consider for a moment that a rails web sever designed to run ruby code and produce text based output.  To do this as quickly as possible very smart people make a number of decisions when writing servers such as puma and raptor. In the case of raptor I know they never allocate a new object during runtime as it's too expensive. They instead maintain a pool of objects for handling incoming requests. The request will be handed and then the objects in the pool released. That's fine for short lived requests but what if you only have 5 objects in your pool? Your sever will very quickly run out of connections as soon as you have 5 people watching a video on your site. While this is happening your site is down to the rest of the world. For more details on how raptor works see http://www.rubyraptor.org/how-we-made-raptor-up-to-4x-faster-than-unicorn-and-up-to-2x-faster-than-puma-torquebox/

Another reason is memory use. A rails server is doing far more complex and high level processing than say nginx. It has smarts in it like connecting to databases and handing sessions. These things don't come for free and cost memory on your server. A front end server such as nginx does not have any of this overhead and can serve video files in the exact same way.

Ideally rails should not even serve static assets such as JS and CSS. Your better configuring your forward facing web server to do this directly to the client. You will have less overhead. Video is a whole other issue on top of that. I would suggest looking at an external hosting service built for hosting video. Amazon has S3 and I am sure there are a few others.

The same argument would go for WEBRick. It's a development server that does not even have the benefit of being compiled. It's pure ruby so it's going to be even worse than say raptor or puma.

Comment: Can you please explain why is that? The information you provided is very interesting. What makes Rails not a good option to stream video? Also, I'll upvote, but not accept the answer as it does not really answer for me

Comment: Hey thanks for the follow up comment. I have expanded my answer. Please feel free to pick it apart and I will do some more research in to things for you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. May I suggest that you also post the link of your research? I've been a big fan of Rails after dealing with JSP and PHP. These things are great to know so I can pick a more suitable language/framework/server, depending on the application

Comment: yeah no problem. I have added it in to the article. Check it out. It's a really great read.

Comment: @Stewart I just read your answer and I get frozen I didn't think about serving assets with rails could be a serious performance topic and even more important when talking about **video** resources. Now I'm thinking about serving files from S3 but what do I need to do to make in the right way? Is it enough setting `src=s3_url` in video html tag?

Comment: @AlexVentura That's where I would start. You want to be linking to the s3 bucket and let it handle the download to the user. Your page can serve up the video player it's self but any content should come from elsewhere

Comment: @Stewart thanks it woks like a charm. Now my video is coming from ***AWS S3*** and my Rails app do not take care about serving this. :)