# Cannot play MP4 video on LAN in iOS through asset pipeline, but can from WAN

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, video, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to embed a `<video>` on my site and show it in a dialog box. I thought there was a JavaScript problem, but I narrowed it down to that fact that iOS Mobile Safari on iPhone will not play a mp4 file from a local network, even with a direct link. The link looks like `http://localhost:3000/assets/introduction-0cf920e06b4224f8f83f59d02f878b7d5733b09590a14147d1580cbfb5081f18.mp4` except I changed `localhost` to the IP of my desktop server. It will load a black screen which is the same color as the first frame of the video with two dashes in the middle.

If I load a hotlink of the MP4 from staging, then it plays fine. It also plays fine in Chrome on the desktop.

I also tried to play in an iPad iOS 9.3.5 and it failed to play, but did display the whole play button, which did nothing.

If I copy the video to the `/public` folder, then it will play on iOS Safari. It seems to only fail when it goes through the asset pipeline, but only in development (same file in staging).

How do I play a MP4 video on iPhone Safari in development environment?

I funneled the iPhone through a Fiddler4 proxy and reloaded the page. It made two consecutive requests:

```
GET /assets/introduction-0cf920e06b4224f8f83f59d02f878b7d5733b09590a14147d1580cbfb5081f18.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.14:3000
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
ETag: "0cf920e06b4224f8f83f59d02f878b7d5733b09590a14147d1580cbfb5081f18"
X-Request-Id: b97a488d-7141-434f-813d-af4848162a70
X-Runtime: 0.058637
Content-Length: 27555596
```

and

```
GET /assets/introduction-0cf920e06b4224f8f83f59d02f878b7d5733b09590a14147d1580cbfb5081f18.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.14:3000
Range: bytes=0-1
X-Playback-Session-Id: A0C3C96E-6F17-47B1-A509-521B3A61D481
Accept-Encoding: identity
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
ETag: "0cf920e06b4224f8f83f59d02f878b7d5733b09590a14147d1580cbfb5081f18"
X-Request-Id: 273865e7-b389-4473-b565-75b2d7ac6559
X-Runtime: 0.038530
Content-Length: 27555596
```

iOS 10.3.3, iPhone 5, Windows 8.1, Rails 5

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this issue. After some tests, I realized it was happening in production as well - this led me to this answer:

[Rails 4 - How to serve video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144628/rails-4-how-to-serve-video)

TL;DR - don't use the asset pipeline for serving video, and if possible, put it outside of your Rails server environment entirely.